# Unable to install package optim in Octave

Tags: octave

I try to install the package optim in Octave using the command

```
pkg install -auto -forge optim
```

But it gives an error:

```
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read version number from package's page
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 49 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 26 column 12
    pkg at line 393 column 29
```

I am not able to resolve this error.

Comment: I'm guessing your internet is down or you have some connection problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens when, for some reason, Octave cannot access the list of latest package releases on Sourceforge.

I have just tried on Octave 4.0.3

```
pkg install -auto -forge optim
```

and it worked:

```
>> pkg install -auto -forge optim
For information about changes from previous versions
of the optim package, run 'news optim'.
```

Sourceforge has been unavaible for some time a few days ago, perhaps is it the reason for the problem that you encountered.

Can you try again and see if the problem still exists?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ubuntu, you can try

```
sudo apt-get install octave-optim
```